# How do I write a 3d astropy table to a file

Tags: python, astropy

I have a 3d astropy table which I'd like to write to a file. 
I created it by converting a 3d numpy array to an astropy table and adding some column names.

Here is an example output of my table. The arrays within each column of each row denote the third dimension.

```
       m_star [14]               m_bh [14]         ... exit_flag [14]
         float64                  float64          ...    float64    
------------------------- ------------------------ ... --------------
3.9782e+32 .. 2.18801e+33 1.9891e+36 .. 1.9891e+38 ...     0.0 .. 0.0
3.9782e+32 .. 2.18801e+33 1.9891e+36 .. 1.9891e+38 ...     0.0 .. 0.0
3.9782e+32 .. 2.18801e+33 1.9891e+36 .. 1.9891e+38 ...     0.0 .. 0.0
3.9782e+32 .. 2.18801e+33 1.9891e+36 .. 1.9891e+38 ...     0.0 .. 0.0
3.9782e+32 .. 2.18801e+33 1.9891e+36 .. 1.9891e+38 ...     0.0 .. 0.0
3.9782e+32 .. 2.18801e+33 1.9891e+36 .. 1.9891e+38 ...     6.0 .. 6.0
```

The way that I write a 2d astropy table to a file is

```
param_table.write(param.txt, format='ascii')
```

But when I try to write a 3d astropy table to a file , I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/astromonerd/HLX1/src/make_dat.py", line 86, in <module>
    dat_table.write(run_dir + '/' + 'dat.txt', format='ascii')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/table/table.py", line 1906, in write
    io_registry.write(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/registry.py", line 374, in write
    writer(data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/ascii/connect.py", line 29, in write_asciitable
    return write(table, filename, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/ascii/ui.py", line 458, in write
    writer.write(table, output)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/ascii/fastbasic.py", line 125, in write
    self._write(table, output, {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/ascii/fastbasic.py", line 139, in _write
    writer.write(output, header_output, output_types)
  File "astropy/io/ascii/cparser.pyx", line 986, in astropy.io.ascii.cparser.FastWriter.write (astropy/io/ascii/cparser.c:17696)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The point is to be able to read the file in by another module and retrieve the astropy table.

Comment: Could you show how you convert a sample numpy array to a astropy table?

Comment: Is this a question about writing a 3d array, or writing an `astropy` table?  With the `numpy` tag you'll get answers from people who know nothing about `astropy`.

Comment: param_table = Table(param_array, names = ('m_star', 'm_bh')

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's anything about this particular to Numpy.  It looks like it might just be a bug in Astropy.

Comment: Part of the problem here is that there's no obvious way to represent this data in a generic ASCII table without some additional special formatting.  So my guess is this *shouldn't* work.  It's just that instead of not working and telling you *why* it's not working, there's just an exception that isn't being caught and giving a useful error, since this usage wasn't anticipated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this using the hdf5 format:

```
param_table.write(param.h5, format='hdf5')
```

Comment: You wanted an ASCII table though didn't you?  So this isn't exactly an answer to the problem.

Comment: I did not require an ASCII table, it was just the convenient format to use in the data table case. For the data cube, I wanted only to write to and read from a data file without losing the structure or the column headers.

Comment: In that case the best currently supported format is probably HDF5; carry on :)